# Regex for 03/19/76 and 03.19.76

Tags: regex

I am new to regex, I have read that regex for

```
03/19/76 and 03.19.76
```

is

```
03[-./]19[-./]76
```

I could not understand why do we need `-` in the regex?

Comment: Not a great regex since it can also match `03.19/76`

Comment: Note that your regex allows `03.19-76` or `03/19-76`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just in case your date is formatted as `03-19-76`. There's no other reason. If you don't want to support this format, remove the minus signs.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `03([-./])19\176` to fix the issue presented in the comments if you want to allow different formats, ie. `-`, `.`, `/`. This captures the first separator into group 1 and looks for that character with the reference `\1`.

Comment: Note that this doesn't work with all regex engines. Many ones don't allow back references and the syntax isn't always this one.